# Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Api::V1::Xxxxx::Xxxxxx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My request works fine in development.
I'm deploying with capistrano and both running rbenv with Ruby 2.1.5 and Rails 4.1.5.

Forgive me, after half of a day trying to get this to work in production and failing miserably I'm resorting to the SO gods hoping for a miracle.

I'm TRYING to develop a versioned api and this all worked before switching to Rails 4.x.x but here is the stack trace:

```
App 10385 stdout: RuntimeError (Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Api::V1::Activities::ReportsController):
App 10385 stdout:   activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:478:in `load_missing_constant'
App 10385 stdout:   activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
App 10385 stdout:   activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:240:in `const_get'
App 10385 stdout:   activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:240:in `block in constantize'
App 10385 stdout:   activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `each'
App 10385 stdout:   activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `inject'
App 10385 stdout:   activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `constantize'
App 10385 stdout:   activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:552:in `get'
App 10385 stdout:   activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:583:in `constantize'
App 10385 stdout:   actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:78:in `controller_reference'
App 10385 stdout:   actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:68:in `controller'
App 10385 stdout:   actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:46:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:45:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
App 10385 stdout:   actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
App 10385 stdout:   actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
App 10385 stdout:   omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
App 10385 stdout:   omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:59:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
App 10385 stdout:   omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
App 10385 stdout:   omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:59:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
App 10385 stdout:   warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
App 10385 stdout:   warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
App 10385 stdout:   rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
App 10385 stdout:   activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
App 10385 stdout:   actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
App 10385 stdout:   railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
App 10385 stdout:   activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
App 10385 stdout:   activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
App 10385 stdout:   activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
App 10385 stdout:   railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   action
App 10385 stdout: pack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
App 10385 stdout:   /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.43/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:74:in `process_request'
App 10385 stdout:   /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.43/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:141:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
App 10385 stdout:   /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.43/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:109:in `main_loop'
App 10385 stdout:   /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.43/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:448:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
```

excerpt from routes.rb:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1) do
      scope 'me', as: :my, defaults: { format: :json, user_id: 'me' } do
        get 'transcript', :controller => 'users', :action => 'transcript', defaults: { format: :pdf }
        resources :attendance, as: :attendance, :controller => 'users/attendance' do
          post 'start', :controller => 'users/attendance'
          post 'complete', :controller => 'users/attendance'
          get 'certificate', :controller => 'users/attendance', defaults: { format: :pdf }

          resources :assessments, as: :assessment, :controller => 'users/attendance/assessments' do
            post 'answer', :controller => 'users/attendance/assessments'
            post 'complete', :controller => 'users/attendance/assessments', :action => 'complete'
          end
        end
        post 'studies', :controller => 'users', :action => 'studies'
        post 'study', :controller => 'users', :action => 'study'
        post 'unstudy', :controller => 'users', :action => 'unstudy'
      end

      resources :me

      resources :users, defaults: { format: :json } do
        resources :attendance, :controller => "users/attendance"
      end

      # scope 'system', :as => :system do
      #   match 'scripts/:action', via: [:get], :controller => 'system/scripts'
      # end
      get 'articles/latest'
      resources :articles, defaults: {format: :json} do

      end
      resources :activities, :path => "activities", :controller => "activities", defaults: {format: :json} do
        # resources :agendas, :path => "agenda", :controller => "activities/agenda"
        # resources :activity_notes, :path => "notes", :controller => "activities/notes"
        # resources :activity_credits, :path => "credits", :controller => "activities/credits"
        # resources :activity_faculties, :path => "faculty", :controller => "activities/faculty"
        # resources :activity_committees, :path => "committee", :controller => "activities/committee"
        # resources :activity_finbudget, :path => "budget", :controller => "activities/budget"
        # resources :activity_finfees, :path => "fees", :controller => "activities/fees"
        # resources :activity_finledgers, :path => "ledger", :controller => "activities/ledger"
        # resources :activity_finsupports, :path => "support", :controller => "activities/support"
        # resources :attendees, :path => "participants", :controller => "activities/participants"
        # resources :activity_application, :path => "application", :controller => "activities/application"
        # resources :activity_pubgeneral, :path => "publish_info", :controller => "activities/publish_info"
        # resources :activity_pubcomponent, :path => "components", :controller => "activities/components"
        match 'reports/:action', via: [:get], :controller => "activities/reports", :defaults => { :format => 'pdf' }
      end
    end
  end
```

and the controller structure is:
app
- api
-- v1
--- activities_controller.rb (extends BaseController)
--- base_controller.rb (extends ActionController::Base)
--- activities
---- reports_controller.rb (extends BaseController)

basics of my files look like this at the api/v1/activities/reports_controller.rb level.

```
module Api
  module V1
    class Activities::ReportsController < BaseController

    end
  end
end
```

if I pull the match route outside of the `resources :activities do` and make it look like this:

```
match 'activities/:activity_id/reports/:action', via: [:get], :controller => "activities/reports", :defaults => { :format => 'pdf' }
```

it seems to like it... but I don't like how that's laid out and it shouldn't have to be that way I don't think...

Comment: you probably have your model name plural where it needs to be singular

Comment: I'm not convinced that's it, but I'll check on it.

Comment: My big thing is why the difference between the environments when they are identical Ruby versions and Rails versions... seems odd to me.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I seem to have resolved it and since this error is seemingly very generic in the Rails world for a number of different issues - I'll share mine although I think it may be valuable to Googlers.

That being said.

I believe my issue was related to configuration of my rails application.
I'm not certain I understand Rails enough to understand the underlying workings and impact of `config.eager_load` but setting it to false for production fixed my issues.

So, in `config/environments/production.rb` I had `config.eager_load = true` which was crashing my  application.

If anyone would like to add to why this may happen or understands this better in comments I can update the answer.

Thanks again for the StackOverflow community and always being there.

Pushing forward feels good.

Comment: You'll want to keep the `eager_load` settings as is, since you don't want your production wasting time loading classes on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change:

```
class Activities::ReportsController < BaseController
end
```

to:

```
class Activities
  class ReportsController
  end
end
```

There are some subtle differences in the way rails does autoloading between the two, and it seems the second is a little easier to resolve. [More info here](http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/) if you're interested.